# How to get RPM build to set installation path correctly

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

This is my first attempt at building an RPM and I'm finding it a bit confusing, not really getting the different variables at all yet, so would appreciate any advice on the below..

I have the following spec file:

```
BuildRoot       : /home/dm40477/rpmbuild/BUILD

%description
Package to deploy PROD Support scripts


%prep

zcat ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/ITRS.tar.gz | tar -xvf -

%install
RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX=/var/opt

%files
%defattr(0622,muser,muser)
/ITRS/bin/SXS
/ITRS/bin/SXSRT
/ITRS/etc/SXS
/ITRS/etc/SXSRT

%changelog
```

It creates the rpm file ok, but when I go to install it on target server, it installs in /bin and /etc

The source file is gziped tar file in the below dir structure which I would like to keep except install it in the folder /var/opt

```
/ITRS/bin/SXS
/ITRS/bin/SXSRT
/ITRS/etc/SXS
/ITRS/etc/SXSRT
```

1. How can I set the install path in the spec file?
2. Do I need to make the dirs to keep the structure, or will it automatically keep that structure?

Any hel appreciated.

Thanks

D

Answer (score 0):

```
RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX=/var/opt
```

sets a variable, RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX, to /var/opt

```
/ITRS/bin/SXS
/ITRS/bin/SXSRT
/ITRS/etc/SXS
/ITRS/etc/SXSRT
```

doesn't reference that variable.

Comment: It shouldn't refer to RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX though, I think its meant to refer to the files in the build folder - this section is just to show a list of the files which should be contained in the build

Answer (score 0):

BuildRoot       : /home/dm40477/rpmbuild/BUILD is ignored now.

try this...

make a file in your homedirectory called .rpmmacros with content like this...

```
%_topdir /home/builder/rpmbuild
```

make sure to use fakeroot to do your building.

cd to /home/builder/rpmbuild and run your rpmbuild command.